# To Apply the validation and set the password and confirm password same in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, validation, react-native, textinput

i'm new in react native. i want to apply the validation if all the fields are filled then it will proceed and if the inputs are not filled it show error and also the pass and confirm password should match . i have applied firebase auth and firebase realtime database.

I have tried many things but none of them working . please help me out in this

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.focusNextField = this.focusNextField.bind(this);
    // to store our input refs
    this.inputs = {};
    this.state = { email: "", password: "", error: "", confirmPassword: "" };

    const { password, confirmPassword } = this.state;
  }

  focusNextField(id) {
    this.inputs[id].focus();
  }
  componentDidMount() {}
  static navigationOptions = {};

  onEnterText = email => {
    if (email.trim() != 0) {
      this.setState({ email: email, ErrorStatus: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ email: email, ErrorStatus: false });
    }
  };

  onButtonPress = () => {
    const { email } = this.state;
    if (email == "") {
      Alert.alert("Please enter the text to proceed");
    } else {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      const { email, password } = this.state;
      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(response => {
          firebase
            .auth()
            .currentUser.updateProfile({
              displayName: email,
              displaypassword: password
            })
            .then(() => {
              // Alert.alert(response.user.uid);
              // firebase.database().ref('fir-login-67a47/' +
              firebase
                .auth()
                .currentUser.uid()
                .set(firebase.auth().currentUser);

              firebase
                .database()
                .ref("sevenup-a1db1//" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .set({
                  email,
                  password
                })
                .then(data => {
                  //success callback
                  // console.log('data ' , data)
                });
              // .catch((error)=>{
              //     //error callback
              //     console.log('error ' , error)
              // })

              firebase
                .database()
                .ref("sevenup-a1db1/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .on("value", function(snapshot) {
                  // console.log(snapshot.val())
                });
              firebase
                .database()
                .ref("sevenup-a1db1/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .update({
                  email,
                  password
                });
            })
            .then(() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate("welcome");
            })
            .catch(error => {
              // let errorCode = error.code
              // let errorMessage = error.message;
              // if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
              //   this.onLoginFailure.bind(this)('Weak password!')
              // } else {
              //   this.onLoginFailure.bind(this)(errorMessage)
              // }
            });
          // console.log(onLoginSuccess.uid)

          //
          console.log(firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword.uid);
        });
    }
  };

  onLoginSuccess() {
    this.setState({
      email: "",
      password: "",
      error: "",
      loading: false,
      confirmpassword: "",
      username: ""
    });
  }

  onLoginFailure(errorMessage) {
    this.setState({ error: errorMessage, loading: false });
  }

  renderButton() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.spinnerStyle}>
          <ActivityIndicator size={"small"} />
          {/* {this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} */}

          {/* loading={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}  */}
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Button
          style={styles.loginButton}
          title="Sign in"
          //   onPress = {this.handleSubmit}

          onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}
        />
      );
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <View>{this.renderComponent()}</View>;
  }
  renderComponent() {
    if (this.state.loggedIn) {
      return (
        <Button
          title="Sign out"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen")}
          title="LoginScreen"
        />
      );
    } else {
      return <LoginForm />;
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          marginTop: 100
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            width: 250,
            borderRadius: 5,
            multiline: "true",
            borderColor: "purple",
            borderWidth: 2
          }}
          label="username"
          placeholder="username"
          // onChange1={this.handleChange}

          value={this.state.username}
          secureTextEntry={false}
          onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.focusNextField("user@mail.com");
          }}
          returnKeyType={"next"}
          ref={input => {
            this.inputs["username"] = input;
          }}
        />

        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            width: 250,
            borderRadius: 5,
            multiline: "true",
            borderColor: "purple",
            borderWidth: 2,
            marginTop: 30
          }}
          label="Email"
          placeholder="user@mail.com"
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.focusNextField("password");
          }}
          returnKeyType={"next"}
          ref={input => {
            this.inputs["user@mail.com"] = input;
          }}
          value={this.state.email}
          secureTextEntry={false}
          onChangeText={email => this.onEnterText(email)}
        />

        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            width: 250,
            borderRadius: 5,
            multiline: "true",
            borderColor: "purple",
            borderWidth: 2,
            marginTop: 30
          }}
          label="Password"
          placeholder="password"
          value={this.state.password}
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.focusNextField("confirmpassword");
          }}
          returnKeyType={"next"}
          ref={input => {
            this.inputs["password"] = input;
          }}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            width: 250,
            borderRadius: 5,
            multiline: "true",
            borderColor: "purple",
            borderWidth: 2,
            marginTop: 30
          }}
          label="confirmpassword"
          placeholder="confirmpassword"
          value={this.state.confirmpassword}
          ref={input => {
            this.inputs["confirmpassword"] = input;
          }}
          secureTextEntry={false}
          onChangeText={confirmpassword => this.setState({ confirmpassword })}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            justifyContent: "flex-end",
            alignSelf: "flex-end",
            alignItems: "flex-end",
            marginRight: 60,
            marginTop: 20
          }}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen")}
          title="LoginScreen"
        >
          <Text>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>{this.renderButton()}</View>
        <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>{this.state.error}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  errorTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    alignSelf: "center",
    color: "red"
  },
  spinnerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  loginButton: {
    marginTop: 30
  }
};
```

Comment: what have you tried? provide a mcve (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ok i have provided you the code

Answer (score 0):

you can create two states to store data respectively, and then compare both of them.
eg...

```
this.state={password:'',c_password:''}
```

and then you can validate with

```
if(this.state.password !== this.state.c_password){
//your error}
else{
//success
}
```